# Checkpoint equivalent of Cisco ASA packet-tracer?

Tags: checkpoint

Is there an equivalent command/function either from CLI or SmartDashboard similar to the ASA 'packet-tracer' command?

For those unfamiliar with 'packet-tracer' - in the ASA CLI we are able to test flows in this manner:

```
packet-tracer input INSIDE tcp 172.16.23.5 1025 8.8.8.8 80 det
```

Where the RFC1918 address is the source, and 8.8.8.8 is the destination.  This command is used to verify rule input and assess which rules a given flow is either being allowed or denied by.

Comment: For those not too familiar with the ASA it may be useful to add a description of what this command does and you're looking for, to improve your chance of getting useful answers.

Comment: Great suggestion, edited !

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

Checkpoint has the *fw monitor* command which should provide similar informations. [This reference](http://yurisk.info/2009/12/12/fw-monitor-command-reference/) looks pretty good.

Answer (score 0):

fw monitor is not equivalent. If you want to check (in limited way compared to ASA) whether packet will be allowed/dropped + and by which rule(s) use command **fw up_execute** from EXPERT mode of checkpoint CLI.
Example:
*#fw up_execute src=1.1.1.1 dst=2.2.2.2 ipp=6 dport=443*